# Dynamic Gradle compile dependencies for different buildConfigFields

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

In my project, I'm using different configurations based on different buildConfigFields, and for some of them I don't use certain dependencies.
So I don't want to have certain dependencies in specific configs, depending on the buildConfigFields.

How can I do something similar to the following?

```
dependencies {
    if (buildConfigField("String", "WHICH_MESSAGE_ENABLED") == "VALUE") {
        compile "xxx.yyy.zz:1.0"
    } else {
        provided "xxx.yyy.zz:1.0"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following in defaultConfig:

```
def mBuildConfigFields

android {
    defaultConfig {
        mBuildConfigFields = buildConfigFields
    }
}

dependencies {
    if (localBuildConfigFields.get("KEY").value == "VALUE") {
        compile "xxx.yyy.zz:1.0"
    } else {
        provided "xxx.yyy.zz:1.0"
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Not working :/

Error:Could not get unknown property 'loadDependency' for object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

Comment: Can you share your build.gradle??

Comment: A build config field is itself a result of some other computation. I'd rather see `def loadDependency = something; if (loadDependency) buildConfigField ...;` It's the same principle as with views and models. Views reflect the state of a model. `loadDependency` is supposed to be the model, `buildConfigField` and `dependencies` reflect the state of `loadDependency`.